# Point of view and rotation

Tags: 3d, transformations, perspective

Two questions which cross over maths/3D imaging/computer science. I'm trying to describe a point of view of an item in a 3d space and subsequently its rotation in a paper I'm writing. Versions I've had read have confused readers.

The scene is as illustrated in the attached image - we are looking on as it were from the left-hand side of the scene.

1. How should I describe the view of the object from the eye symbol? I've termed it a "thirty degree elevated front view" - it's the 'front' that I think is most problematic.
2. Then if the object is rotated backwards along the x axis how do I describe that? I've said "transformation, specifically a rotation seventy degrees backwards along the x axis".

Are these the correct way of describing this point of view and rotation?

[image: point of view]

Answer (score 1):

You could phrase it in terms of elevation away from various planes. So 30° above the x-z plane, and 0° from the y-z plane (or whatever it actually is). It's sort of like [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) where you'd have theta and phi.

Answer (score 1):

Just say, that the angle between the surface and the vector pointing from the object to the camera is 30 degrees.

To describe rotations, I suggest using the "yaw, pitch, roll":

[image: yaw pitch roll]

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a paper, you should just explain what you mean by your terms in the beginning of the paper, and include your illustrations (preferrably rendered in 3D)

Comment: That's a good suggestion for clarity. Even so, if they misuse terms or write obscurely, it'll hurt their credibility in the paper, so it's wise to check even if they include the diagram.

Comment: I see your point